# Index multidimensional array with index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array of index tuples and I would like to use it to pick out values from a multidimensional numpy array,

```
import numpy
a = numpy.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
idx = [[1, 1, 2], [0, 3, 7], [9, 8, 4], [9, 9, 9]]
```

The comprehension `[a[i, j, k] for i, j, k in idx]` only worked if `a.ndim` was known.

Any hints?

Comment: By the way, `len(a.shape)` is acessible via `a.ndim`

Comment: Cool, never knew about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could convert the transposed version of `idx` to a tuple and then index for a vectorized solution -

```
a[tuple(np.transpose(idx))]
```